# Python 3.4 list to do different tasks

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = [
         'aapl':'apple',
         'tgt':'target',
         'nke':'nike',
         'mcd':'Mc Donald',
         'googl':'google',
         'yhoo':'yahoo',
         'rl':'Polo Ralph lauren'
        ]
```

I wish to execute this

```
q = 0
while q < len(list1): 
   code_to_be_executed 
   q = q+1
```

But only for the 1st part (aapl,tgt,nke,mdc,rl,yhoo,etc) and the the 2nd part (the company name as google, yahoo , polo ralph lauren, etc ) to be printed in something like this : nke = nike to the user
The problem is it will perform the q task to everything even for the company name which is not what I want) I know I could seperate the abreviations and the company name in two different list but how could I print it like the nke = Nike comp. ? thank you very much

Comment: First of all; the syntax is all wrong. You are describing a ``dict()`` here really except you're missing the *curly braces*.

Comment: @james Mills I edit it thanks for the heads up

Comment: Are these now supposed to be tuples in a list? If so the syntax is still incorrect. You need to clarify your data structure here.

Comment: and still wrong syntax :) replace `[` to `{` and `]` to `}`. i.e. you want to create `dict` but use syntax for `list`

Answer (score 3):

What I believe you are trying to do is a basic printing of a key/value data structure (*called a `dict` in Python*):

**Example:**

```
data = {
    'aapl': 'apple', 'tgt': 'target', 'nke': 'nike', 'mcd': 'Mc Donald',
    'googl': 'google', 'yhoo': 'yahoo', 'rl': 'Polo Ralph lauren'
}

for k, v in data.items():
    print("{0:s}={1:s}".format(k, v))
```

Which outputs:

```
$ python app.py 
nke=nike
tgt=target
aapl=apple
mcd=Mc Donald
rl=Polo Ralph lauren
yhoo=yahoo
googl=google
```

**Update:** If you still want to do this with a `while` loop with a `q` variant then your data structure **will have to be** a "list of tuples" -- Where each "tuple" is a key/value pair. e.g: `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`

**Example:** (*based on your code more or less*)

```
data = [
    ('aapl', 'apple'),
    ('tgt', 'target'),
    ('nke', 'nike'),
    ('mcd', 'Mc Donald'),
    ('googl', 'google'),
    ('yhoo', 'yahoo'),
    ('rl', 'Polo Ralph lauren)')
]

q = 0  # counter
while q < len(data):
    k, v = data[q]  # assign and unpack each tuple (key, value)
    print("{0:s}={1:s}".format(k, v))
    q += 1
```

**NB:** This data structure is mostly the same except that you loose the benefits of being able to do `O(1)` lookups. Dictionaries/Mappings are more suited to this kind of data structure especially i you intend to perform lookups base don keys.

Comment: It's just `items` in Python 3.

Comment: @James Mills but what do I change to the q = 0
while q < len(list1): 
   code_to_be_executed 
   q = q+1 part?

Comment: You don't need a custom loop construct here to iterate though this data structure which matches what you described above buy using a dictionary. Replace ``print(...)`` with a block of code you want.

Comment: @James Mills I got the thing right but I do not understand what k and v stands for? Can you redirect me to a page explaining it or can you explain it to me so I can understand what I am doing? thanks :)

Comment: Updated with some helpful comments.

Comment: @bob you should begin your path in python not from SO, instead look for sites like [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/dictionary-manipulation-in-python). In the example above k,v represents tuple of key and value created by generator.